# Laravel 8, Tailwind CSS init

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css

I have tried to install Tailwind CSS. I have run the following command.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

However, I have an error.

> Unexpected token {

Maybe someone had the same mistake. I have an empty Laravel instance and I want to add tools for the UI.

Comment: Which version of nodejs are you using? Try upgrading to 14 if it's not the case and try again. The problem could be with postCSS. Getting the latest nodejs version will most probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have the latest package versions.

```
npm install -D laravel-mix@latest tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/921)

Actually the problem is with node/npm version. Try to upgrade the node version which is compitale with tailwindcss.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by upgrading NodeJS to the latest stable version.

```
sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable
```

then

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./path/style.css -o ./path/output.css --watch
```